# Server deployed to AWS - How to use Proxy/VPN?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vpn

I'm asking for help here as I'm about to go crazy. I have backend NodeJS server using Express deployed to AWS. My server was working fine but it looks like I've broken the ToS of some of the APIs that my server is using and they've black-listed my IP.
I now need to fix it. I've been doing some research and googling to find what's the best way. So far people have recommended:

1. Using a VPN
2. Using a Proxy
3. A career change into gardening.

Since it's almost winter here in the UK, I've discarded option Nr 3 for now.
What is the best practice here? I'm currently using a trial of NordVPN and it works fine with a nice UI.
Is there any "specific" VPN provider that is "developer friendly"? Something like a Stripe for payments but for VPNs.
Instead of VPNs some people suggested using proxies. I'm a self-taught developer so I've got no clue how to solve this.